# How to set the repeating alarm which will work even in Doze mode?

Tags: android, performance, android-doze-and-standby

I understood that setExactAndAllowWhileIdle will invoke alarm even in Doze mode but how to make it repeat every day because there is no setRepeatingAndAllowWhileIdle kind of method.

Comment: Inside your code that is invoked by the alarm event, call `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` to set up the next alarm event.